# How to align two plots in the center of three column plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot where I have 14 plots in total. So, I plot 3 plots in each row. In the last row, there are two plots left which can be plotted at specific column number. However, to make the graph look more synchronous, how can the last two plots can be plotted in center of columns. Below is the picture that I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.gridspec` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,20),tight_layout=True)
    
    spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=8, nrows=3, figure=fig)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,1:3])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,3:5])
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,5:7])
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,1:3])
    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,3:5])
    ax6 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,5:7])
    ax7 = fig.add_subplot(spec[2,2:4])
    ax8 = fig.add_subplot(spec[2,4:6])
    plt.show() # bbox_inches='tight'
```

Result:
[image: Gridspec Result]